# Appengine Rapid Application Development Platform

Tags: google-app-engine

I am not sure whether i should call this next big idea but we need to take rapid application development to next level.

Example : I type in google search (assuming i am logged in using google account)

@appspot @myemployeeapp #select name,address from employee where rating >10

Outcome : Should Generate working appengine app 
http://myemployeeapp.appspot.com

[this app will automatically generate various screens to create,edit,delete,update employee name,address,rating.

This will revolutionize the way non programmers can generate and organize data with a single query and focus on their business problem.

1.My question to this community : Are there any tools which help me generate UI based on my datastore model or sql query. I want standard UI based on the model and relationships.

1. Are there any other rapid development tool this community wants to recommend on appengine platform.

Answer (score 0):

[Grails](http://www.grails.org/) with [Grails AppEngine plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/app-engine), maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I think Grails will be right choice for your requirement. It provide the scaffold view for your domain model.